# Loop through a directory and perform action on files with specific permissions in unix

Tags: unix, sh

I want to loop through a directory with many subdirectories that have hidden files. I want to loop the directory and open only files that have some certain permission, "drwx-----T+" in this case.

My current script is

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /z/vendors  #vendors has a list of directories which contain hidden files
for FILE in *; do
    if [ <what should i put here to select files with permission "drwx-----T+">]; then
        cd "$FILE" #and do something here e.g open the hidden files
        cd ..
    fi
done
```

I don't know what test condition to use, I know the command `ls -l | grep "drwx-----T+"`  will list the files I need but how can I include this in the `if` test

Comment: Use `find -perm` to match files with the given permission.

Comment: I've never heard of a version of `find` without `-perm`.

Comment: Do you have the `stat` command?

Comment: My bad ```find ... -perm``` works on the system, let me try using it

Comment: And use `-type d` to match directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exit status of `grep` indicates whether the input matched the pattern. So you can use it as the condition in `if`.

```
if ls -ld "$FILE" | grep -q -F 'drwx-----T+'; then
    # do what you want
fi
```

The `-q` option prevents `grep` from printing the match, and `-F` makes it match a fixed string rather than treating it as a regular expression (`+` has special meaning in regexp).

Comment: The if condition works, however the ```find ... -perm``` seems more appropriate for this, my bad for commenting that it wasn't working

Comment: Feel free to post your own answer that shows how to do it with `find -perm`.